# AWS Aurora: Calling lambda from Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We have an RDS AWS Postgres database cluster (v13.7) from which we want to be able to invoke a Lambda function. We have carefully followed the directions laid out in [this AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html#PostgreSQL-Lambda-Event) and paid special attention to our RDS security group allowing TCP traffic to port 443 and to any IPv4 addresses (0.0.0.0/0).

Using psql to connect to the database, we have been running the following command to try and invoke a lambda call:

```
SELECT * from aws_lambda.invoke(aws_commons.create_lambda_function_arn('arn:aws:lambda:ca-central-1:123456789012:function:lambda-postgres-test', 'ca-central-1'), '{"body": "Hello from Postgres!"}'::json, 'Event');
```

However the result is the following error after about 30s:

```
ERROR:  invoke API failed
DETAIL:  AWS Lambda client returned 'curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached'.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "invoke" statement 1
```

It feels like this is some simple inbound or outbound rules issue but so far nothing we have tried has changed the outcome. Does anyone know about another change that may be required to permit RDS Postgres to invoke a lambda?

Also: our RDS Postgres cluster is publicly available and so we've followed the security-setup directions from the AWS docuement labelled: "To configure connectivity to AWS Lambda for a public DB instance"

Comment: Is Aurora running in a VPC subnet without a NAT Gateway, or Lambda VPC Endpoint?

Comment: @Mark B: Yes, its a publicly accessible db (ie not private) and so we followed the AWS document's section labelled "To configure connectivity to AWS Lambda for a public DB instance"